# How call application.properties in the separate module

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I have multiple modules in spring boot application. I have for module A `@SpringBootApplication` and for module B I have `@SpringBootApplication`. 
Problem is because in the A module I had application.properties but in module B I do not have, but module B mast to use same application.properties from A module. Does anyone know how to set globar application.properites for all modules?

Answer (score 0):

Proposal: create a parent module which has your submodules `A` and `B` and a new `core` module. The core can contain everything you need in your other modules like `application.properties`. Add a dependency to `core` at your `A` and `B` module.

Set up your `@SpringBootApplication` in the parent.

Comment: Ok, a set application.properties in the main module and now my modules A and B do not recognize the application.properties.

Comment: I edited my answer, now it should work as you want it without creating a direct dependency between `A` and `B`. Sorry for the first misleading answer :/

Answer (score 0):

What are your dependencies between the modules?

A suggestion would be if module B includes module A as a dependency.

Then you can start `@SpringBootApplication` from module B and it should work.